# Redirecting a Website with Directory using cPanel

Tags: url, directory, cpanel, redirect

So I used to have a website and now I own a new website.
I would like everyone who goes on that website to be redirected to the new one. 
I have successfully done that with the main root but I am unable to do it with a directory. Example
www.Example1.com/root -> www.Example2.com
Anyone know how to do this with cPanel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create that redirection through cPanel. If you are getting any issues with cPanel then I will suggest you please add redirection rule in.htaccess file at www.Example1.com/root/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do it via .htaccess. Just add following line in .htaccess of the old domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldwebsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldwebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newwebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Make sure you replace your domain in the above lines.